# Vaultwarden on Nginx can be accessed via IP address, but not domain name

Tags: nginx, web-hosting, raspbian

I'm pretty new to hosting in any capacity, but I had a spare raspberry pi laying around and figured I'd try running my own Bitwarden setup with nginx. I am able to access the Bitwarden page with my ip address, so I know for a fact it's at least working. However, I can't access the web page with the domain I own. I currently own the domain willjp.dev and have a an A Record pointing willjp.dev to my IP address.

This is my sites-enabled/default file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name willjp.dev; #domain name
  return 301 https://www.willjp.dev$request_uri;

}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name willjp.dev; #domain name

  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/willjp.dev.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/willjp.dev.key;

  client_max_body_size 128M;  # Allow large attachments

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /notifications/hub {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3012;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /notifications/hub/negotiate {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }
}
```

It is port forwarded, I have a static IP address, and I disabled gzip. These are all solutions I have tried from lurking forums.

If anyone could help me with this, I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: What error are you encountering?  What errors are being emitted to `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?

Answer (score -1):

That IP probably won't work, as 0.0.0.0 shouldn't be routable. If you are trying to hit another process listening on a different local port, then you'll need to reference localhost or the loopback interface--which is normally 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thank you sir, I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: @WillPeterson did this answer actually solve your problem?  Because `0.0.0.0` in the context you used it should work just fine, as `INADDR_ANY` should establish a connection to any bound interface listening on the port specified, 8080 in this case.

See more: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419880/connecting-to-ip-0-0-0-0-succeeds-how-why